# Error term for backward differentiation formula

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, extrapolation, finite-difference-methods

I am trying to derive the error term for the backward differentiation formula $f'(x) \approx \frac{3f(x)-4f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{2h}$.

By Taylor expansion

$f(x-h)=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)-\frac{h^3}{6}f^3(\xi_a)$,

$f(x-h)=f(x)-2hf'(x)+2h^2f''(x)-\frac{4h^3}{3}f^3(\xi_b)$.

So in forming the linear combination I get $\frac{3f(x)-4f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{2h}=f'(x)+\frac{h^2}{3}f^3(\xi_a)-\frac{2h^2}{3}f^3(\xi_b)\leq f'(x)+\frac{2h^2}{3}|f^3(\xi)|$, where $|f^3(x_0)|\leq|f^3(\xi)|$ for all $x_0\in(x,x-2h)$.

So $\frac{2h^2}{3}|f^3(\xi)|$ is the error bound. But the notes I am following, which uses an identical method, ends up with $\frac{16}{3}$ as the coefficient for $h^2$ in the error formula (i.e. $\frac{16h^2}{3}|f^3(\xi)|$ is the error bound). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The expected error is second order, so consider and treat with the extended mean value theorem
\begin{align}
&\frac{3f(x)-4f(x-h)+f(x-2h)-2hf'(x)}{2h^3}
\\[.5em]
&=\frac{4f'(x-h_1)-2f'(x-2h_1)-2f'(x)}{6h_1^2}
\\[.5em]
&=\frac{-4f''(x-h_2)+4f''(x-2h_2)}{12h_2}
\\[.5em]
&=-\frac{f'''(x-h_3)}3
\end{align}
where $0<h_2<h_1<h$ and $h_3\in[h_2,2h_2]$, so that finally
$$
\frac{3f(x)-4f(x-h)+f(x-2h)}{2h}=f'(x)-\frac{h^2}3f'''(\xi), ~~ \xi\in[x-2h,x]
$$
This means that the error term is even smaller than the one that you derived.

Comment: I never thought to use this method so thanks. But where exactly does my method using Taylor series fail?

Comment: It did not fail, you got essentially the same result in the combination of the Taylor expansions, only that there is no nice way to combine the 3rd derivatives. The formulation of the upper bound is also somewhat wrong. // The last step here is impossible or difficult to achieve with Taylor polynomials and remainder terms. The coefficient can be achieved using cubic Taylor polynomials with 4th order remainder terms, but then there remains an $O(h^3)$ error from the combination of remainder terms.

Comment: You should have written $...=f'(x)+R$ with $|R|=\frac{h^2}3|f'''(\xi_a)-2f'''(\xi_b)|\le h^2|f'''(\xi)|$. There is no guarantee that the third derivatives have the same sign.